# primefaces radio button not workng(radio button value not parsed to bean class)?

Tags: primefaces, radio-button

Xhtml Page:

```
<p:outputPanel id="customPanel" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
     <p:selectOneRadio id="radiobutton" value="#{a.date}" layout="custom">
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Month:" itemValue="date" />
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Date :" itemValue="date1" />
     <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
      </p:selectOneRadio>
       <p:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="0"
                                        style="border:hidden; padding:1px;">
                                        <p:radioButton id="opt1" for="radiobutton" itemIndex="0" />
                                        <h:outputLabel for="opt1" value="Select Month:" />
                                        <p:calendar pattern="MMM-yyyy" navigator="true" />

                                        <p:radioButton id="opt2" for="radiobutton" itemIndex="1" />
                                        <h:outputLabel for="opt2" value="Select Date :" />
                                        <p:calendar  navigator="true"/>
                                    </p:panelGrid>
           </p:outputPanel>
```

Bean Class:

```
@ManagedBean(name="a")
            public class A
    {
            private String date ;


            public String getDate() {
                    return date;
                }

                public void setDate(String date) {
                    this.date = date;
                }
            System.out.println(" Date : " + date);
    }
```

The Selected date value is not getting xhtml page to bean class.when i click submit button after selecting any radio button the error was displayed.. form:radiobutton: 'date' could not be understood as a date.please suggest any solution to parse radio button value xhtml page to bean class.

Comment: Your itemValue is a string and the value of the selectOneRadio is date. How do you expect form to submit?

Comment: I tried with String datatype in bean class.That is also not working.please suggest any other solution – Mahendran Ayyarsamy Kandiar

Comment: If you choose String it won't **work** because the options are p:calendar which will set a date. And no I won't suggest another solution. I did not suggest anything in the first comment either. I just commented for you to figure it out. If I wake up and see no answers or helpful comments tomorrow then I will tell you the answer.